# How are declarative languages executed by a computer?

Tags: programming-languages, declarative-programming

I'm getting introduced to declarative languages and am beginning to love them. In particular Haskell, a functional language, is very expressive, easy to debug. But my question has to do with execution. Are such languages compiled or interpreted? If it is the latter then I would have to choose conventional languages like C++ or Java for performance reasons. But I would love to use declarative languages for their increased productivity and ease of maintenance.
Eager to hear from the esteemed members of this community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no universal answer for all languages; it just depends on what's been implemented for a particular language.  Haskell, in particular, can be either compiled or interpreted.  Some declarative languages may only have interpreters currently, but a compiler could be written in the future.

Also, don't assume that just because a language implementation is interpreted, it's unusable "for performance reasons".  Depending on the application, interpreted code may still be fast enough.

Comment: As an example about interpreted code performance, [TrufflC](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2647528) is a C interpreter built on top of the JVM that runs on average only 7% slower than GCC/Clang compiled C does.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of declarative languages, they cannot be executed in their purely declarative form; see e.g. the [*An intelligent system can and must use declarative knowledge efficiently* paper of J.Pitrat](http://An%20intelligent%20system%20can%20and%20must%20use%20declarative%20knowledge%20efficiently), or several entries of his [blog](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/) e.g. ["stop programming!"](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/01/stop-programming/), ["CAIA, my colleague"](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/04/caia-my-colleague/), ["know thyself"](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/03/know-thyself/), etc...

So a declarative system is transforming the declarative knowledge into executable procedures, or interpreting it procedurally, or often a mix of both approaches.

J.Pitrat's mentra is that such work on declarative knowledge can and should be expressed in a declarative way (thru declarative meta-knowledge able to be applied to itself), with a [bootstrapped](http://bootstrappingartificialintelligence.fr/WordPress3/2014/06/the-meta-bug-curse-of-the-bootstrap/) system.

BTW, his CAIA system has lot of declarative knowledge and is bootstrapped, so translated itself into hundreds of thousands of lines of C.

You could follow his example and work on a declarative system which generates Java code, but it is a long journey... Your system will then have a "compiler" part, that is something which contextually translates some declarative knowledge into executable Java code.

Likewise, Haskell may transform (i.e. compile) some expression into *several* forms of code, depending upon the context, etc...